# colouring rows in a subgrid based on a cell value CRM 2016

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2016

Does anyone know if it's possible to do this? I've seen it used for previous CRM instances but I can't seem to find anything for CRM 2016 on-line. All is help appreciated greatly.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look here:
http://dynamicsofdynamicscrm.com/2014/10/24/adding-row-colours-to-crm-2013-sub-grids-dynamically-based-on-value-in-cells/

This JavaScript should work to in CRM 2016 on-line. But I should tell you, that this solution is unsupported.